# How to access the command line for Tesseract from Python?

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I am using Python to do some processing, and I need to OCR with Tesseract. Is there a way I can, from python, type this:

"tesseract --tessdata-dir /usr/share imagename outputbase -l eng -psm 3"

into the command line somehow or its equivalent?

thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling an external command in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

See the example below.

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "localhost"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, err = p.communicate()
print  output
```

Output:

```
Pinging w10-PC [::1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from ::1: time<1ms 
Reply from ::1: time<1ms 
Reply from ::1: time<1ms 
Reply from ::1: time<1ms 

Ping statistics for ::1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

Replace `["ping", "localhost"]` in the example with

```
["tesseract", "--tessdata-dir", "/usr/share", "imagename", "outputbase", "-l", "eng", "-psm", "3"].
```

You may further check [examples](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/python-execute-unix-linux-command-examples/) here, this [execute-shell-commands-in-python](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/238180/execute-shell-commands-in-python) question and [Python 2.7 doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) for more information.