# How to use trained data with pytesseract?

Tags: ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

Using this tool http://trainyourtesseract.com/ I would like to be able to use new fonts with pytesseract. the tool give me a file called *.traineddata

Right now I'm using this simple script :

```
try:
    import Image
except ImportError:
    from PIL import Image
import pytesseract as tes

results = tes.image_to_string(Image.open('./test.jpg'),boxes=True)
file = open('parsing.text','a')
file.write(results)
print(results)
```

How to I use my traineddata file so I'm able to read new font with the python script ?

thanks !

edit#1 : so I understand that `*.traineddata` can be used with Tesseract as a command-line program. so my question still the same, how do I use traineddata with python ?

edit#2 : the answer to my question is here [How to access the command line for Tesseract from Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42966322/how-to-access-the-command-line-for-tesseract-from-python)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below is a sample of `pytesseract.image_to_string()` with options.

```
pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open("./imagesStackoverflow/xyz-small-gray.png"),
                                  lang="eng",boxes=False,
                                  config="--psm 4 --oem 3 
                                  -c tessedit_char_whitelist=-01234567890XYZ:"))
```

To use your own trained language data, just replace `"eng"` in `lang="eng"` with you language `name(.traineddata)`.

Comment: A small addition to the above answer: Keep xyz.traineddata file in the path where tesseract data is kept (example: /usr/share/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/) and pass following : `pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open("./imagesStackoverflow/xyz-small-gray.png"),lang="xyz")`

Comment: `.traineddata` is appended to the lang name and whitelist is broken in OpenCV 4.

Comment: So if my file is in `a.traineddata` and my language is "eng", by your instructions, would I do: `lang="eng(a.traineddata)"`?